# mysqli statement not displaying else for no result

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli

I have a statement, quite basic that pulls in from a database and displays the information. It works. However if I delete the entry in the database, the else statement should kick in a say that there are no results. However it does not. Can anyone see the problem?

This is the code, the bit I'm taking about is the  `if($result) {`

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }else {
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE status ='0'");

        if($result) {

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<li><a href=\"current_vacancy?id=".$row['id']. "\">". $row['title'] ."</a> <img src=\"rightarrow.png\" alt=\"next\"></li>";
            }

        } else {
        // execute for 0 rows returned.
            echo "There are currently no vacancies available";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does var_dump($result) shows?

Comment: Why do you have $result in the first line. Moreover its matching closing brace is missing.

Comment: sorry, the  if($result) { added wrongly into the code when it should have been in the text above. edited

Answer (score 2):

If the `SELECT` operation was successful then `mysqli_query()` will always return an object. Whether this object holds 0 or more records it will always be true. What you should rather have done instead is fetch all the records from the result.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");
$con->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE status ='0'");
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);

if ($data) {
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        echo "<li><a href=\"current_vacancy?id=".$row['id']. "\">". $row['title'] ."</a> <img src=\"rightarrow.png\" alt=\"next\"></li>";
    }
} else {
    // execute for 0 rows returned.
    echo "There are currently no vacancies available";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To implementing no result, you need to check number of rows you fetch by query with `mysqli_num_rows()`.

In your case you checked for the $result variable this will store the status of the query execution, therefore it will always be true, since query will always execute even if it returns no rows.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more natural way

```
$data   = [];
$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM vacancies WHERE status ='0'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
?>
```

and now you may use `$data` the way you tried to use $result:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <li>
      <a href="current_vacancy?id=<?=$row['id']?>">
        <?=$row['title']?>
      </a>
      <img src="/images/rightarrow.png" alt="next">
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>

<?php if(!$data): ?>
        There are currently no vacancies available
<? endif ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The result returned from [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/mysqli_query) is an object, not a row count.  Use `mysqli_num_rows($result)` to get the row count.

By the way, be sure to call `mysqli_free_result($result)` at the end.  Suggested outline:

```
$result = mysqli_query(…);
if (!$result) {
    # Handle failure
} else {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
        # Handle no vacancies
    } else {
        # Normal case
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: at the end of the if, before the else?