# Extract from database to form select

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

Working on a project where I am going to extract from my database and show the pool name in a form select. But very unsure how to go further than this.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","nih_bw");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $sql = "Select name from pools";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');

 }

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Code's incomplete. Closing bracket missing before `mysqli_close()`

Comment: you may try some tutorial or at least other questions in category. [The very recent one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22857402/mysqli-statement-not-displaying-else-for-no-result) for example

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","nih_bw");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"Select name from pools");
echo "<select name='mypool'>";

$default_name = "foo_bar"; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $opt_name = $row['name'];
  $str_selected = "";
  if($opt_name == $default_name){
      $str_selected = "selected";
  }
  echo "<option value='".$opt_name."' ".$str_selected." >" . $opt_name. "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

You can see an introductory article here:http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_mysql_select.asp

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, getting error in the select name=mypool. What is it going to be there ?

Comment: There's an error for `'".$opt_name/"'>` as it has to be `'".$opt_name."'>`

Comment: @user3185936 Sorry, I made a misstype on the line "Select name from pools". I fixed it on the above answer, so could you try again.

Comment: @naota My pleasure .... I see a minor mistake in your code that's why I edit this to correct it.

Comment: Do you mean selected attribute  `<option value="..." selected>` ? I will add sample code.

Comment: Yes, that is what i actually meaned.

Comment: @user3185936, I added some lines above. Is it what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Try using your query like this:

```
<select name="batch">
    <option value="">Select One</option>
    <?php 
    $pd=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `pools`");
    $pd->execute();
    foreach($pd->fetchAll() as $rw) :
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rw['id'];?>"><?php echo $rt['name'];?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

It is in pdo, but you will get my logic.

Comment: and I wonder if they ever stop upvoting irrelevant answers too

Comment: @YourCommonSense :) I am fluent with pdo, therefore I elaborated my logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you. (Code is not tested)

```
<?php
    $record = array();
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","nih_bw");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $sql = "Select name from pools";
    if(!$result = mysql_query($sql,$con)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
    else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $record[] = $row;
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
<select>
    <?php
        foreach($record as $value){
            echo "<option>".$value."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Getting errors here:  if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){ --ERROR: Undefined variable: db

Comment: What driver you mean @your common sense?

Comment: Your code is mixing `mysqli_*` with `mysql_*` functions, the reason why it's failing for the OP. @BlankHead Those two API's do not mix. Actually you can mix them if you know how to, but not in this case.